# what's meaning, process is not in an inherited sandbox, when i run my helper app within a electron build app

Tags: macos, electron, sandbox, appstore-sandbox

I have a electron-build app and a helper app within my app.
Everything works fine expect building my app for mac app store.
when call my helper app, i encountered crashed, process is not in an inherited sandbox.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9tDK.png)

my helper app build by xcode
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8k8T0.png)

my main app build by electron

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjFzF.png)

my electron plist[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4vFB.png)

I have tried using app group, but does not find clear docs.

any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.